# What is the advantage of using TestServer for ASP.net core integration tests?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I am now at the point where I want to test my application and found [FluentDocker](https://github.com/mariotoffia/FluentDocker.git) which allows me to run all my infrastructure as a xUnit test fixture. So far so good. The issue is that then I run not only my infrastructure, but also my application server as a docker container part of the docker-compose.

From my understanding this means I will not be able to use the [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver) facilities. Most of the examples I see seem to use the TestServer to shape the test environment. I actually do not want to shape the test environment, I want it to be as faithful to the deployment as possible, with configurations being managed by the docker-compose file.

Is my approach wrong? Am I buying a lot future effort in test setup? As my understanding on the abilities of the TestServer are the most lackluster, what is the advantage of using TestServer for ASP.net Core integration tests?

Comment: A docker-based testing acts like a real server which is suitable for black box tests. However, `TestServer` gives us more control over the testing. A good example is the [NTLM authentication testing](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/8c02467b4a218df3b1b0a69bceb50f5b64f482b1/src/Security/Authentication/Negotiate/test/Negotiate.Test/NegotiateHandlerTests.cs#L98): It must throw when you send anonymous req just between the stage1 & stage2 authentication. This behavior is hard to be test when you use a real server.

Comment: 2. (too long to be pasted into a single comment) Another fact is TestServer needs no further runtime to test your code, while docker is not. This might be important if we should run our tests frequently.  For example, it's difficult to test your code on Win10 Home edition if you use the docker-based testing. However, a TestServer solution make our test available for all kinds of machines.

Comment: Hello Itminus, thanks for the answer. As I actually am running in Linux, and only targeting linux the docker infra should not be a concern. The NTLM also not. If you believe this is about it, please post it as an answer and I will accept the answer. So for blackbox integration tests there is not anymore advantage? In the meantime of this question I have further ahead and the concept i proposed is turning out very powerful and not fragile.
Also, control over tests is only necessary to hit the logic reachable by a user. In my point of view testing non reachable logic is not useful.